# Search based on selected column in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, search, stored-procedures

I have table Student having ID, FirstName, LastName columns.

```
Student Table - ID, FirstName, LastName
```

I will pass ColumnName and searchText to procedure.

```
e.g. ColumnName=FirstName, SearchText="John"

And the procedure will return the records having FirstName as John.
```

How to write procedure for this?

Comment: Well, how much do you know about stored procedures so far? Have you written any code so far?

Answer (score 0):

You must write this procedure using dynamic SQL. It's not recommended approach for many reasons, but technically it can be done, in this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_search
    @filterCol nvarchar(100)
   ,@filterVal nvarchar(100)    
AS
BEGIN
    declare @query nvarchar(100)
    SET @query = 'SELECT * '
               + ' FROM TableB'
               + ' WHERE ' + @filterCol + ' = @0'
    exec sp_executesql @query, N'@0 nvarchar(100)', @filterVal
END
```

Note that the variables should be escaped to aviod SQL injection.

Comment: can you elaborate on why it is not a recommended approach please. if i only had transact-sql as a tool in that case i really don't see any other possibility as creating a dynamic query in this way. what would be the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

Because your table definition is so small, there are only three columns that could be queried.  And the definition of the problem suggests that you don't have to search on more than one column at a time.  That means you can write a stored procedure that takes a search value (SearchText) and a control parameter (ColumnName) that indicates what column is to be searched.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentSearch
(
    @ColumnName  varchar(50)
,   @SearchText  varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   ID
         ,   FirstName
         ,   LastName
    FROM     [Student Table]
    WHERE    (@ColumnName = 'FirstName' AND FirstName = @SearchText)
       OR    (@ColumnName = 'LastName'  AND LastName = @SearchText)
END
```

If the problem requires that you be able to find a name based on a substring, you would use `FirstName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'` instead, but your example didn't say that.

This isn't feasible when more than one column is searched on at a time, and it gets complicated when the columns to be searched are not strings.  But this meets the needs of the problem as you specified it.

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure V_search
 @firstname varchar(50),
 @lastname varchar(50)

As 
 Begin 
 Declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

Set SQL=SQL +' Select * from student C where

```
                                    c.first_name like ' + CASE WHEN @firstname IS NOT NULL
                                            THEN 'LOWER('''+@firstname+''') '   
                                            ELSE 'LOWER(c.first_name) ' 
                                        END

                                     +'AND c.last_name LIKE ' +  
                                        CASE WHEN @lastname IS NOT NULL
                                            THEN 'LOWER('''+@lastname+''') ' 
                                            ELSE 'LOWER(c.@lastname) ' 
                                        END 
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table student
( 
ID_no varchar(50),
firstname varchar(50),
lastname varchar(50),
section varchar(50),
Department varchar(50),
Place varchar(50) );

Create procedure V_search
 @firstname varchar(50),
 @lastname varchar(50)

As 
Begin 
 Declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

 Set @SQL = ' Select * from student C where  

                                    c.firstname like ' + CASE WHEN @firstname IS NOT NULL
                                            THEN 'LOWER('''+@firstname+''') '   
                                            ELSE 'LOWER(c.firstname) ' 
                                        END  +

                                     'AND c.lastname LIKE ' +  
                                        CASE WHEN @lastname IS NOT NULL
                                            THEN 'LOWER('''+@lastname+''') ' 
                                            ELSE 'LOWER(c.lastname) ' 
                                        END +''
Print @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL


END 
go

Exec V_search 'rag%',null
```